# Data cable types for internal DVD writers

Tags: motherboard, cable, optical-drive

What are the possible data cable types to connect DVD writer to motherboard? What are the differences between them? Do I have to use only one type for a writer or is it optional?

My motherboard is `GigaByte P43-ES3G` and my DVD writer is `LG GH22NP20`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two *datacables* out there, [IDE aka PATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Drive_Electronics) and [SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA). Your DVD-Writer is an IDE one, and the pictures from Google tell me that your Motherboard has IDE-Sockets, so there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](http://gadgetophilia.com/sata-pata-and-scsi-a-comparison/) to see features of SATA, IDE/PATA and SCSI technologies. There is also a thorough comparison.